# problemas claves foraneas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una base de datos que alberga datos de transporte publico y tengo un pequeño desface

este es mi SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`lineas` (
 `idlineas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `numero` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idlineas`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`trayectos` (
`idtrayectos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ramal` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`itinerario` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idtrayectos`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`tipo_buses` (
`idtipo_buses` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descripcion` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idtipo_buses`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`empresas` (
`idempresas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idempresas`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`operador` (
`idoperador` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idoperador`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`lectores` (
`idlectores` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`serie` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idlectores`, `serie`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba`.`buses` (
`idbuses` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idtipo_buses` INT NOT NULL,
`idlineas` INT NOT NULL,
`idtrayectos` INT NOT NULL,
`idempresas` INT NOT NULL,
`idoperador` INT NOT NULL,
`idlectores` INT NOT NULL,
`serie` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`chapa` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
`coche_numero` INT NOT NULL,
`observaciones` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idbuses`, `idtipo_buses`, `idlineas`, `idtrayectos`, 
`idempresas`, `idoperador`, `idlectores`, `serie`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_tipo_buses_tipo_buses1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idtipo_buses`)
  REFERENCES `prueba`.`tipo_buses` (`idtipo_buses`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_lineas_lineas1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idlineas`)
  REFERENCES `prueba`.`lineas` (`idlineas`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_trayectos_trayectos1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idtrayectos`)
  REFERENCES `prueba`.`trayectos` (`idtrayectos`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_empresas_empresas1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idempresas`)
  REFERENCES `prueba`.`empresas` (`idempresas`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_lectores_lectores1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idlectores` , `serie`)
  REFERENCES `prueba`.`lectores` (`idlectores` , `serie`));
```

como verán puse como candidatos únicos dentro la tabla buses a chapa y numero de coche para que estas no se repitieran, pero al insertar los datos no estoy pudiendo hacer que tanto el idlectores o id operador no se repitan es decir, en la tabla buses pueden existir 2 buses que tengan hasta el mismo operador el mismo lector y eso en la practica no deberia ser asi y no estoy pudiendo encontrar donde pueda corregir eso, pienso que sea un problema de claves foraneas, me podrian ayudar porfavor

[image: como se ve la BD]

Update: Realice los cambios que me aconsejaron, asi quedo la tabla pero de nuevo tengo el mismo problema
2 buses de distintos que tienen el mismo operador y mismo lector..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Viendo a vuelo de pájaro tu tabla `buses` no hay que analizar mucho para ver que hay un grave error de diseño. La tabla `buses` debe almacenar **entidades únicas** que sería cada bus en particular, irrepetible. Dices que *en la tabla buses pueden existir 2 buses que tengan hasta el mismo operador el mismo lector y eso en la practica no deberia ser asi*  y es correcto. Para **que no sea así** lo que debes hacer es **sacar esas columnas de la tabla `buses` y crear una nueva tabla asociativa que maneje esas relaciones**. No sé si me entiendes lo que te quiero decir. Tu diseño es erróneo.

Comment: Tratando de adivinar lo que hace tu sistema, podemos imaginar una tabla asociativa como esta: `buses_trayectos` con las columnas `idbuses, idtrayectos, idlectores, idoperador`... Es un ejemplo, suponiendo que **un bus por trayecto tiene un solo lector y un solo operador**. Si en un mismo trayecto el mismo bus puede tener varios operadores o varios lectores, entonces el modelo deber plantearse de otro modo. Es sólo para dar una idea de cómo hacer para dejar a la tabla `buses` independiente de operadores y lectores, como debe ser.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, solo para entender mejor, en esa tabla buses debería de haber 500 buses que pertenecen a X empresa, cada bus tiene su trayecto pero hay varios buses que siguen el mismo trayecto, si debería ser una relación de muchos a muchos allí verdad? que abarque operadores, lectores, trayectos...

Comment: Correcto una relación muchos a muchos expresada en una tabla asociativa. En la tabla buses estarían todos los buses sin importar de que empresa sea. Las demás relaciones deben ir fuera de la tabla buses , según el modelo. La clave es pensar que ciertas tablas representan una entidad, tal es el caso de buses (una fila por cada bus) y que otras tablas manejan las relaciones entre esas entidades.

Comment: Actualice la base de datos segun lo que me recomendaste el problema es que por ejemplo inserto 2 buses y ellos terminan compartiendo el lector y el operador como al principio

Comment: En la tabla `buses` no deben existir las columnas relativas a `lector` y `operador`, esas columnas deben ser trasladadas a la tabla asociativa que gestionará las relaciones. [Es precisamente lo que he explicado en este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189939/problemas-claves-foraneas?noredirect=1#comment355904_189939) en una hipotética tabla llamada `buses_trayectos`.

Answer (score 0):

La tabla `buses_has_trayectos` tiene columnas redundantes. Veamos de arriba para abajo esa tabla:

- `idtipo_buses, idlineas, idempresas,`  no las necesitas ahí, ya existen en la tabla `buses`.
- debes decidir cuál será la columna que enlazará con `lectores`, si `serie`  o `idlectores`. No tiene sentido poner ahí dos columnas de la misma tabla relacionada.

La tabla puede quedar así:

#### `buses_has_trayectos`

`idbuses`

`idtrayectos`

`idlectores`

`idoperador`

Si la tabla va a manejar una relación *muchos a muchos*, significa que tendrá `n` filas que exprese la cantidad de relaciones de ese tipo.  Es decir, si en un mismo trayecto (trayecto con id 4 por poner un ejemplo) el bus 1 tiene dos operadores (operador 2 y operador 7) y dos lectores (lector 1 y lector 8), esa relación se expresaría así.

```
idbuses     idtrayectos     idlectores     idoperador
---------------------------------------------------------
1           4               1              2
1           4               8              7
```

Si quieres los datos de operadores y lectores de un determinado bus/trayecto sólo tienes que hacer una consulta uniendo las tablas relacionados y con un `GROUP BY idbuses, idytrayecto`.

Si quieres cualquiera de las columnas que sacamos de la tabla porque sobraban, sólo tienes que tomarlas de las tablas en que están, porque ellas participan del `JOIN` que vas a hacer.

---

**NOTA:** No significa que el ejemplo de relación *muchos a muchos* expuesto más arriba sea el más idóneo (es sólo para explicar cómo funciona). Este modelo sería óptimo si siempre en un trayecto un bus tiene la misma cantidad de lectores y de operadores. En un modelo donde un bus puede tener por ejemplo 1 operador y 5 lectores o viceversa, habría que plantear la relación de otra manera.  ¿Por qué?  Porque un modelo donde vas a tener *filas o columnas haciendo nada*, es un mal modelo de datos.

Por ejemplo imaginemos que en un bus/trayecto puede haber 6 lectores y sólo 2 operadores:

```
idbuses     idtrayectos     idlectores     idoperador
---------------------------------------------------------
1           4               1              2
1           4               8              7
1           4               9              NULL
1           4               10             NULL
1           4               11             NULL
1           4               12             NULL
```

Tendrías que re-pensar el modelo de datos, no es bueno tener cuatro columnas haciendo nada en el caso de `idoperador`.

Las forma de resolver esto son múltiples: desde trasladar la relación a otra tabla relacionada con trayectos o con grupos o zonas de operadores / lectores, hasta usar columnas del tipo `ENUM` para indicar quién opera y quien lee en cada bus/trayecto.

Son sólo ideas... no te puedo decir más sin conocer a fondo el modelo de datos y lo que hace la aplicación.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: excelente explicación, pero no es lo que estoy queriendo hacer al fin al cabo tomare ese ultimo cuadro que hiciste

Answer (score 0):

es muy buena la explicación en serio te agradezco el tiempo tomando los 2 ultimos cuadros que hiciste,

```
idbuses     idtrayectos     idlectores     idoperador
---------------------------------------------------------
1           4               1              2
1           4               8              7
1           4               9              NULL
1           4               10             NULL
1           4               11             NULL
1           4               12             NULL
```

y también un ejemplo de lo que sucede:

```
idbuses     idtrayectos     idlectores     idoperador
---------------------------------------------------------
1           4               1              7
2           4               1              7
```

Hay 2 buses compartiendo el mismo lector y operador, esto es lo que quiero evitar.
Para ello me vi en la necesidad de poner como único los fk idlectores e idoperador de esa manera evito que se repitan como mostré mas arriba, esta es la solucion que le di yo, no se si la mas adecuada al caso pero es la unica que se me ocurrio.

Comment: Lamentablemente no has sido claro en tu planteamiento. Para evitar eso lo que tienes que hacer es crear una restricción en la tabla que impida que haya más de una fila con los mismos datos, en esa restricción debes poner todas las columnas que no se pueden repetir. Eso se puede hacer al crear la tabla con ` UNIQUE (col1,col2,con)` o con un `ALTER TABLE ` si la misma ya está creada. [Lee esto](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) para más información.